# Replacement variable in list plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I would like the replacement:

```
/. {ComplexInfinity -> 0}
```

to be treated as a variable.

I am trying to overlay the following list plots:

```
g1 = (d = (q = 20;
 f = (lop = 
    Transpose[{Flatten[
       Reverse[
         Table[Zeta[y], {y, 0, q}]] /. {ComplexInfinity -> 0}],
      Flatten[Table[x^n, {n, 0, q}]]}];
   {#1*#2} & @@@ lop);
 Flatten[f];
 Total[f]);
sol = Solve[d == 0];
r = ListPlot[{{Re@x, Im@x} /. sol}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Black];
Show[r, PlotRange -> {{-q/10, q/3}, {-q/10, q/10}}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 800]);

g2 = (d = (q = 20;
 f = (lop = 
    Transpose[{Flatten[
       Reverse[
         Table[Zeta[y], {y, 0, q}]] /. {ComplexInfinity -> 1}],
      Flatten[Table[x^n, {n, 0, q}]]}];
   {#1*#2} & @@@ lop);
 Flatten[f];
 Total[f]);
sol = Solve[d == 0];
r = ListPlot[{{Re@x, Im@x} /. sol}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Black];
Show[r, PlotRange -> {{-q/10, q/3}, {-q/10, q/10}}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 800]);

...
```

For:

```
Show[{g1, g2, g3.....}]
```

Is there an easier way to do this - ie, in a single command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about defining a function:

```
cplot[m_] := g1 = (d = (q = 20;
 f = (lop = 
    Transpose[{Flatten[
       Reverse[
         Table[Zeta[y], {y, 0, q}]] /. {ComplexInfinity -> m}], 
      Flatten[Table[x^n, {n, 0, q}]]}];
   {#1*#2} & @@@ lop);
 Flatten[f];
 Total[f]);
 sol = Solve[d == 0];
 r = ListPlot[{{Re@x, Im@x} /. sol}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> Black];
 Show[r, PlotRange -> {{-q/10, q/3}, {-q/10, q/10}}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 800])
```

Now you get the first plot with cplot[0] and the second with cplot[1]. You can plot many different ones with (for instance)

```
cplot[#] & /@ Range[5]
```

which plots the first 5.

Comment: @ Bill s = Many thanks for your help on this - works really well :-)

Comment: @ Bill s, Is there any way I could use something similar to Show[cplot[Range[5]]]?

Comment: @ Bill s, Can't seem to get it to work on similar plots...:-/

Comment: I've updated to show you how to make it work on many. You need only define the functions -- be careful of the syntax, note the `:=` and the underscore `m_` (two common early mistakes).

Comment: @ Bill s, Many thanks - realised resizing issue with other plots - update really useful :-)